# can't put two divs beside each other

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have two divs one inside of the other, now i want to put show the child div called `subMenu` appears beside the div father, when the event was mouseEnter in the div father called `prueba`. The event works well my problem it's with the css I'm stock. how can i solve this?

**my html**

```
<div id="prueba" class="ui-state-hover" style="width:150px;height:20px;float:left">category
</div>
<div style="float:left"> other thing </div>
```

**My Js**

```
$(document).ready(initialize);

function initialize() {
    $('#prueba').hover(showSubMenu, hideSubMenu);
}
function showSubMenu() {
    var subMenu = '<div id="subMenu" class="ui-state-hover" style="width:150px;position:relative;top:0px;left:100%">subCategory</div>';
    $('#prueba').append(subMenu);
}

function hideSubMenu() {
    $("#subMenu").remove();
}
```

[here's my live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/justelnegro/JyqyZ/)

**UPDATE**
I don't want that the div that have the text `other thing` move of his position. i want that subMenu appears over this div

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of creating the submenu everytime, you can check if its exists just use it. In the `hideSubMenu` method instead or `remove` you can just `hide` it.

Try this

Working **[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/KkppS/5/)**

```
  $(document).ready(initialize);

  function initialize() {
    $('#prueba').hover(showSubMenu, hideSubMenu);
  }
  function showSubMenu() {
    if($("#subMenu").length == 0){
       $(document.body).append('<div id="subMenu" class="ui-state-hover" style="width:150px; float: left;">subCategory</div>');
    }
      $("#subMenu").css({
          position:'absolute',
          top: $('#prueba').offset().top,
          left: ($('#prueba').offset().left + $('#prueba').width())
      }).show();
  }

  function hideSubMenu() {
    $("#subMenu").hide();
  }
```

Comment: Your edited fiddle is much better than my solution. I just did it a quick and lazy way =p

Answer (score 2):

Here you go, try this.

```
$(document).ready(initialize);

function initialize() {
    $('#prueba').hover(showSubMenu, hideSubMenu);
}
function showSubMenu() {
    var subMenu = '<div id="subMenu" class="ui-state-hover" style="width:150px; float: left; position: relative; top: -20px; left: 150px;">subCategory</div>';
    $('#prueba').append(subMenu);
}

function hideSubMenu() {
    $("#subMenu").remove();
}
```

[new demo](http://jsfiddle.net/KkppS/4/)

Comment: that's good but i don't want to move other div with the text `other thing`

Comment: Ok, I edited my answer. Check it out. You can use the CSS z-index property to have elements appear on top of each other.